# what does 2 ideals are equal mean?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I'm revisiting the proof of 1-1 correspondence theorem and while proving $f$ is one-one
  I don't know how to write mathematically what we mean by 2 ideals are equal?
(Here  $f$ is a map from set of all ideals of $R$ containing $A$ to set of ideals of $R/A$:=    $f(B)=B/A$).

Does equality of 2 ideals means equality element wise .
Please help....

$\small($ *correspondence theorem is stated as follows:
Let A be an Ideal of ring R.There is 1-1 correspondence between Ideals of B containing A and ideals of R/A* .$\small)$

Comment: Do you know what it means for two subsets of a set to be equal...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi no I'm not clear with what it means,does it means equality elementwise...

Comment: It's not about two ideals being equal but about two sets of ideals being equal. Moreover the corresponding ideals are not necessaraly equal. Example: The set of ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$ containing the ideal $12\Bbb{Z}$ (like $4\Bbb{Z}$) corresponds $1\leftrightarrow 1$ to the ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$. Here the ideal corresponding to  $4\Bbb{Z}$ is $3\Bbb{Z}_{12}$. The former ideal has $\infty$ elements the latter $4$.

Comment: thanks @Nimda for making it clear to me...

Comment: @Nimda How is your explanation related to proving $f$ one-one?I mean here in my answer ain't I proving equality of two ideals and not their sets.Please if you can explain it to me....

Comment: @spectraa I thought that there was confusion about two ideals of different sets being equal. This has nothing to do with your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here for simply proving that $f$ is one-one ,you can do this:=
                  $f(B_1)=f(B_2)\implies B_1/A=B_2/A$
                                $\implies \exists b_1 \in B$ and $b_2 \in B_2$
                         s.t. $b_1+A=b_2+A$ and then proceed...